# service fails to start after restart

Tags: windows, services, login

This issue happens on XP SP3 and on Win7 SP1.  The service is configured to run using a service account to logon as a service.  When I manually enter the password it is accepted and is given logon as a service right.  Then once the computer is rebooted the service does not start due to no password saved.

below is the error

```
Event ID 7041
service was unable to log on as contoso\$serviceaccount with the currently configured password due to the following error: 
Logon failure: the user has not been granted the requested logon type at this computer.

This service account does not have the required user right "Log on as a service."
```

Answer (score 2):

My problem was that I had, not sure why, logon as a service defined at the domain level which was stepping on the service after every reboot.  I added the domain service account to the domain group policy that was setting the logon as a service, did a gpupdate /force and was able to start the service.

Answer (score 1):

You need to [grant that account the "log on as a service" right](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc739424%28WS.10%29.aspx).

(on your domain controller)